# Use up and down arrows for autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are many examples onauto complete with jquery in google *"eg searching facebook like search jquery"*

But I cant find any that show how can you use the up and down arrow keys to scroll down on the results.

My "results" div contains a list of results as shown below:

So how I can scroll down on my results using the up and down arrow keys and the below code?

```
<form id="search-form" method="get" action="search.php">
    <input class="search-terms" type="text" value="Search" autocomplete="off" name="resultsFor" /> 
    <input class="submit-search" type="submit" value="go" /></form>
    <div id="results" class="shadow" style="display: none;">
      <h4 class="tophit-title" style="background-color: #4AABD8">Top Hits</h4>
      <ul id="tophit-list">
        <li>a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;url.com?act=view&amp;id=4 &quot;&gt; 
        <img width="62" height="62" alt="img sample" src="http://127.0.0.1/sample.JPG" /> 
        <span>a carton o 
        <b>f</b> mil</span></li>
        <li>a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;url.com?act=view&amp;id=2 &quot;&gt; 
        <img width="62" height="62" alt="img sample2" src="http://127.0.0.1/sample2.JPG" /> 
        <span>a carton o 
        <b>f</b> mil</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

This is my jquery function:

```
$(".search-terms").keyup(function (e) {
    var searchbox = $(this);

    switch (e.keyCode) {

        case 38:
            alert("UP");
            break;
        case 40:
            alert("DOWN");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your question/problem ?

Comment: Are your not correctly capturing the events or what is your problem? If you are actually asking for a function that navigates through your search results with up and down keys, you will find no answer here, because there is no universal solution to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic function to move through a list using the arrow keys.

```
$("ul").keydown(function (e) {
    var searchbox = $(this);
    switch (e.which) {
        case 40:
            $('li:not(:last-child).selected').removeClass('selected')
                 .next().addClass('selected');
            break;
        case 38:
            $('li:not(:first-child).selected').removeClass('selected')
                 .prev().addClass('selected');
            break;
    }
});
```

We can apply this to a form with an input to move the selected item. The focus needs to remain on the input for this to work

```js
$(".search-terms").keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 40:
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent moving the cursor
      $('li:not(:last-child).selected').removeClass('selected')
        .next().addClass('selected');
      break;
    case 38:
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent moving the cursor
      $('li:not(:first-child).selected').removeClass('selected')
        .prev().addClass('selected');
      break;
  }
});

$('.search-terms').keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 1) {
    $('#results').show();
  } else {
    $('#results').hide();
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search-form" method="get" action="search.php">
  <input class="search-terms" type="text" value="" placeholder='Search' autocomplete="off" name="resultsFor" />
  <input class="submit-search" type="submit" value="go" /></form>

<div id="results" style="display: none;">
  <h4 class="tophit-title" style="background-color: #4AABD8">Top Hits</h4>
  <ul tabindex='1'>
    <li class='selected'>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I modified this slightingly (http://jsfiddle.net/magkia/fwZXx/11/)  the weird thing both your example and mine works in Mozilla but not IE

Comment: @Athanatos Weird, it works for me in IE. (or are you referring to JSFiddle ?)

Comment: strange.. what version are you using? I am using IE 10.

Comment: @Athanatos same. Does it just not move on button press?

Comment: @Athanatos are you testing it directly from IE ? (JSFiddle does not support IE)

Comment: Your example works in both IE and Mozilla, my example (http://jsfiddle.net/magkia/fwZXx/13/) doesn't work IE through jsfiddle or direct , I am using the key press event directly on the input box (click on the input box and then press up and down).

Comment: @Athanatos Ahhhh, I wanted to mention! change `(e.keyCode)` to `(e.which)`

Comment: Also I was using jquery 1.1 in jsfiddle which is a very old version, thanks for all the help :) .updated fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/magkia/fwZXx/18/

Comment: How does this work? While the user is typing, the focus is on ".search-terms". Thus, the keyup & keydown events get generated on the text box and not on ul. I've exactly similar code and my function ul.keydown never gets called... Please advice if I'm missing the obvious

Comment: @TusharTarkas thanks for pointing it out. My answer was not toned for the HTML the OP provided and we ended up finishing in the comments. Yes, the keydown event needs to be triggered by the input because that element is being focused. I've edited my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the projects I was on I recalled making something like that. I dug up the code for your inspection (DSL stands for Dynamic Search List):

```
var dslTimer = [];
var dslData = [];
var dslControls = [];
var dslSelected = [];
var dslSelectedIndex = 0;

var callBackFunction;

function addDsl(inputField, dslPlaceHolder, dslUrl, maxDepth, callback, countryLimitation) {
    var dslIndex = dslControls.length + 1;
    dslControls[dslIndex] = [inputField, dslPlaceHolder, dslUrl, maxDepth, countryLimitation];
    callBackFunction = callback;

    $('#' + inputField).keyup(function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (key == '13') {
            if ($('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).hasClass('hidden') && $('#' + inputField).val().length > 0) {
                if (callback == null) {
                    $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).closest('form').submit();
                }
                else {
                    callback();
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).addClass('hidden');
            }
        } else if (key == '38') {
            //Up key
            $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li:nth-child(' + dslSelectedIndex + ') a').removeClass('highlight');
            dslSelectedIndex -= 1;
            if (dslSelectedIndex < 0) {
                dslSelectedIndex = $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li').length;
            }
            $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li:nth-child(' + dslSelectedIndex + ') a').addClass('highlight');

            var str = $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li:nth-child(' + dslSelectedIndex + ') a').text();
            if (str != null && str != "") {
                $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][0]).val(str);
            }
        } else if (key == '40') {
            //Down key
            $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li:nth-child(' + dslSelectedIndex + ') a').removeClass('highlight');
            dslSelectedIndex += 1
            if (dslSelectedIndex > $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li').length) {
                dslSelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li:nth-child(' + dslSelectedIndex + ') a').addClass('highlight');

            var str = $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul li:nth-child(' + dslSelectedIndex + ') a').text();
            if (str != null && str != "") {
                $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][0]).val(str);
            }
        } else {
            var input = $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][0]).val();

            if (input.length >= 2) {
                window.clearTimeout(dslTimer[dslIndex]);
                dslTimer[dslIndex] = window.setTimeout('doDsl(' + dslIndex + ')', 100);
            }
            else {
                $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).addClass('hidden');
            }
        }
    });
    $('#' + inputField).blur(function(e) {
        window.setTimeout('blurDsl(' + dslIndex + ')', 500);
    });

    return dslIndex;
}

function doDsl(dslIndex) {
    getDsl(dslIndex, $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][0]).val());
}

function getDsl(dslIndex, searchstring) {
    if (searchstring.length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    var postData = { 'input': searchstring, 'maxDepth': dslControls[dslIndex][3] };
    if (typeof (dslControls[dslIndex][4]) != 'undefined' || dslControls[dslIndex][4] != null) {
        postData.countryId = dslControls[dslIndex][4].val();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: dslControls[dslIndex][2],
        data: postData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        timeout: 60000,
        global : false,
        success: function (data) {
            (data.length > 0)
                ? showDsl(dslIndex, data)
                : blurDsl(dslIndex);
        }
    });
}

function showDsl(dslIndex, data) {
    dslData[dslIndex] = data;
    dslSelected[dslIndex] = null;

    var htmlString = '<ul>';
    var searchText = $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][0]).val().ignoreAccent();

    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        var text = item.Text;
        var accentlessText = item.AccentlessText.Value;

        var boldStart = accentlessText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
        while (boldStart > -1 && searchText.length > 0) {
            text = text.substring(0, boldStart) + '<strong>' + text.substring(boldStart, (boldStart + searchText.length)) + '</strong>' + text.substring((boldStart + searchText.length), text.length);

            boldStart = accentlessText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase(), (boldStart + 17 + searchText.length));
        }
        htmlString += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmousedown="selectDsl(' + dslIndex + ', \'' + item.Id + '\')" tabindex="' + (1000 + i) + '">' + text + '</a></li>';
    });
    htmlString += '</ul>';

    $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1] + ' ul').replaceWith(htmlString);

    dslSelectedIndex = 0;
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).removeClass('hidden');
    }
}

function selectDsl(dslIndex, id) {
    $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).addClass('hidden');
    $.each(dslData[dslIndex], function(i, item) {
        if (item.Id == id) {
            $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][0]).val(item.Text);
            dslSelected[dslIndex] = item;
            if (callBackFunction != null) {
                callBackFunction();
            }
        }
    });
}

function blurDsl(dslIndex) {
    $('#' + dslControls[dslIndex][1]).addClass('hidden');
}

// Source: https://github.com/zimny/accentless
(function () {
    if (String.prototype.ignoreAccent) return;

    var AccentCharCodesTable = {
        "a": [224, 229],
        "A": [192, 198],
        "c": [231, 231],
        "C": [199, 199],
        "e": [231, 235],
        "E": [200, 203],
        "i": [236, 239],
        "I": [204, 208],
        "n": [241, 241],
        "N": [209, 209],
        "o": [242, 246],
        "O": [209, 214],
        "s": [353, 353],
        "S": [352, 352],
        "u": [248, 252],
        "U": [216, 220],
        "y": [253, 253],
        "Y": [221, 221],
        "z": [382, 382],
        "Z": [381, 381]
    };

    String.prototype.ignoreAccent = function() {
        var i, currentCharCode, char, str = this.split("");

        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            currentCharCode = str[i].charCodeAt(0);
            if (currentCharCode < 192) continue;
            for (char in AccentCharCodesTable) {
                if (AccentCharCodesTable.hasOwnProperty(char)) {
                    if (currentCharCode >= AccentCharCodesTable[char][0] && currentCharCode <= AccentCharCodesTable[char][1]) {
                        str[i] = char;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return str.join("");
    };
})();
```